# Update quantity of duplicate product in cart reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a cart. I'm adding item to cart on click `addToCart`. However, it adds a duplicates of the same items, and not increasing it's quantity in cart. I also have an `incrementCount` and `decrementCount` for updating quantity of added items in cart. I want to make a function which will both `add to cart` and `update the quantity in cart if item is the same`

I also have a problem with my increment/decrement - it changes quantity of all added items, not the particular one I clicked. Also I want it to update `cartTotal` every time I'm clicking on `incrementCount/decrementCount`.

Here is the sandbox code
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-night-s575k?file=/src/components/Menu.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have separate state variable `count` for each product thats in your cart.
You need to have your components like so

`Cart` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

export default function Cart({
  product,
  removeFromCart,
  count,
  incrementCount,
  decrementCount
}) {
  const { image, title, price } = product;

  return (
    <>
      <li className="cart-item__container">
        <img src={image} alt={title} className="cart-item__image" />
        <h4 className="cart-item__title">{title}</h4>
        <h5 className="cart-item__price">{price}$</h5>
        <button disabled={count === 1} onClick={() => decrementCount(product)}>
          -
        </button>
        <span>{count}</span>
        <button onClick={() => incrementCount(product)}>+</button>
        <FaTimes
          className="icon__remove"
          onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}
        ></FaTimes>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

`Menu` component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from "react-tabs";
import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css";

import { FaShoppingCart } from "react-icons/fa";
import products from "./products";
import Product from "./Product";
import Cart from "./Cart";

const Menu = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (el) => {
    const cartCopy = cart.slice();

    const index = cartCopy.findIndex((product) => el.id === product.id);

    if (index === -1) {
      cartCopy.push({ ...el, count: 1 });
    } else {
      const pr = cartCopy[index];
      cartCopy[index] = { ...pr, count: pr.count + 1 };
    }

    setCart(cartCopy);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (el) => {
    const cartCopy = cart.filter((product) => el.id !== product.id);

    setCart(cartCopy);
  };

  const decrementCount = (el) => {
    const cartCopy = cart.slice();

    const index = cartCopy.findIndex((product) => el.id === product.id);

    const pr = cartCopy[index];
    cartCopy[index] = { ...pr, count: pr.count - 1 };

    setCart(cartCopy);
  };

  const getCartTotal = () => {
    return cart.reduce(
      (total, product) => total + product.price * product.count,
      0
    );
  };

  const getCartCount = () => {
    // return cart.length;
    // =======OR=========
    return cart.reduce((total, product) => total + product.count, 0);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs className="tabs-wrapper" id="menu">
        <TabList className="tabs">
          <Tab className="tab-item">Burgers</Tab>
          <Tab className="tab-item">Lunch of the day</Tab>
          <Tab className="tab-item">Crepes</Tab>
        </TabList>
        <TabPanel>
          <div className="burgers">
            <ul>
              {products
                .filter((product) => product.category === "burger")
                .map((product) => (
                  <Product
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    addToCart={addToCart}
                  />
                ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <div className="lunch">
            <h4>Sweet lunch today!</h4>
            <span>7$</span>
            <p>
              You can choose one of our 3 sweet crepes + one of our 4 cold
              drinks!
              <br />
              Nutella crepe, Crepe with salted caramel and nuts or Oreo Bang
              crepe with whipped cream and raspberries.
              <br />
              For drink - one of our homemade lemonades - Melon, Orange or
              Lemon-Mint. Or a Frozen Coffee!
            </p>
          </div>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <div className="crepes">
            <ul>
              {products
                .filter((product) => product.category === "crepe")
                .map((product) => (
                  <Product
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    addToCart={addToCart}
                  />
                ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
      <FaShoppingCart className="cart-icon">{getCartCount()}</FaShoppingCart>
      {cart.map((el) => (
        <Cart
          key={el.id}
          product={el}
          count={el.count}
          removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
          incrementCount={addToCart}
          decrementCount={decrementCount}
        />
      ))}
      <h4 className="cart__total">Your Order Total Price: {getCartTotal()}$</h4>
      <button className="btn__clear" onClick={() => setCart([])}>
        Clear cart
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Oooh, I see. Thanks. So I don't need another hook for a counter